# calling 'map' method on Searchkick::Results object returns always same order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I have a User model with following spec:

```
def search_data
    {
        full_name: full_name,
        published: published,
        sn: sn
    } 
end
```

Then I try to get ordered results on `sn` field. This is my query:

`User.search("pablo", order: {sn: :asc}, fields: [:full_name], limit: 10)`

Inspecting the resulting object reveals that it is working as expected:

`User.search("pablo", order: {sn: :asc}, fields: [:full_name], limit: 10)` gives:

```
#<Searchkick::Results:0x007feae41a3958
 @klass=User,
 @options={:page=>1, :per_page=>10, :padding=>0, :load=>true, :includes=>nil, :json=>false},
 @response=
  {"took"=>75,
   "timed_out"=>false,
   "_shards"=>{"total"=>1, "successful"=>1, "failed"=>0},
   "hits"=>
    {"total"=>5,
     "max_score"=>nil,
     "hits"=>
      [{"_index"=>"users_production_20150409165753551", "_type"=>"user", "_id"=>"551598ba32663300160d0000", "_score"=>nil, "sort"=>[1]},
       {"_index"=>"users_production_20150409165753551", "_type"=>"user", "_id"=>"54e3ba1d6538630003090000", "_score"=>nil, "sort"=>[2]}]}}>
```

You can see that first item in `hits` is the one supposed to be. If I run the query specifying descending order then first `hits` item is the one with `sn` 2. However, when I call `#map` method on Searchkick::Results object it always returns the same order not matter the order specified.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `order: { _sn: :asc }`?

Comment: What are expecting from `#map` ? `#map` is supposed to manipulate the format not the order.

Comment: @SharvyAhmed, what do you mean? Who are you referring to? What do you mean with the format? It's called over an Enumerator and returns an Enumerator right?

Comment: @borjagvo, yes I was asking you. I didn't understand the line - "when I call #map method on Searchkick::Results object it always returns the same order not matter the order specified".

Comment: @SharvyAhmed got you. #map iterates over each item in the order they are on the Enumerator. As you say, it doesn't manipulate the order, hence when different order (:asc/:desc) is applied, it should return a different ordered array.